# Save exr/pfm as little endian

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, visual-c++, cimg

I am load a bmp file into a **CImg** object and I save it into **pfm** file. Successful. And this **.pfm** file I am using it into another library, but this library *doesn't accept big-endian*, just **little endian**.

```
    CImg<float> image;
    image.load_bmp(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.bmp"));
    image.normalize(0.0, 1.0);
    image.save_pfm(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.pfm"));
```

So, how can I save **bmp file to pfm file** as **little endian**, **not** *big endian* .. it is possible ?

**Later edit:**

I have checked first 5 elements from .pfm header file. This is the result **without invert_endianness**:

```
CImg<float> image;
image.load_bmp(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.bmp"));
image.normalize(0.0, 1.0);
image.save_pfm(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.pfm"));

PF
512
768
1.0
=øøù=€€=‘>
```

and this is the result **with invert_endianness**:

```
CImg<float> image;
image.load_bmp(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.bmp"));
image.invert_endianness();
image.normalize(0.0, 1.0);
image.save_pfm(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.pfm"));

PF
512
768
1.0
?yôx?!ù=‚ì:„ç‹?
```

Result is the same.

Comment: Add the PFM header lines that you get with and without using `invert_endianness()` into your question. The _Scale Factor / Endianness_ line is most important.

Comment: I removed that line from code and from post ... with that line, or without, the outcome is the same.

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: I have answer yet due to errors using code from above: error C2079: 'is' uses undefined class 'std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [22]' to 'int'
note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Comment: I updated the first post ... seem that invert_endianness has no effect ...

Comment: Seem pretty clear to me that invert_endianness has no effect ... I double checked ...

Comment: Let me check another few lines beyond first three of them.

Comment: Updated again the first post.

Comment: Great, that's the output I needed. Indeed, it doesn't look like it's inverting endianness. What happens if you do like this: 1. Read the BMP, 2. Write PFM. 3. Read PFM. 4. Invert endianness. 5. Write PFM again.

I'm thinking that perhaps `CImg` can't invert endianness on a BMP - but it's a longshot.

Comment: ...but one thing: The _actual_ image bytes in the PFM files you have shown are different with and without `invert_endianness`. What happens if you manually go in and change the scale factor/endianess from `1.0` to `-1.0`? Or if you `image.invert_endianness();` **after**  `image.normalize(0.0, 1.0);`? What are those normalizing values supposed to do anyway? They look a bit strange to me.

Comment: Without image.normalize(0.0, 1.0); when I convert the image with https://convertio.co/pfm-bmp/ the image is black. That is why I normalize the image ...

Comment: Ok, but the actual values you use does not look like those used in the examples I saw in the documentation. I've just downloaded `CImg` myself and will try it out.

Comment: I called image.invert_endianness(); after image.normalize(0.0, 1.0);, the same outcome ... no difference at all. I don't think that manually change scale from 1.0 to -1.0 would solve the problem ... as far as I understood is about data arrange as well ..

Comment: Just take the memorial.jpg from here: http://www.pauldebevec.com/Research/HDR/PFM/ and convert it as bmp, and you'll see the same results ... I happy by your attention ! :) I really appreciate !

Comment: I made my own `.bmp` and have tested different approaches with no success either - but from what I can see in the actual data in the `pfm` file, inverting endianess seems to actually switch the endianess on _some of it_ so I wouldn't give up just yet. :-)

Comment: No, I would not give up ! :) Thank you Ted !!!

Comment: "inverting endianess seems to actually switch the endianess on some of it" Did you identified the data that should be switched/modified inside CImg oject ?

Comment: No, I just looked at the hexdump. :-) I'll post something in a few minutes, just finalizing my result.

Comment: Hello Ted, I was out of office few days. I will try your solution and I'll let you know the outcome.

Comment: If you look in `CImg.h` around line 60,802 you'll see it always writes `1.0` as the scale factor, i.e. never `-1.0` like this `std::fprintf(nfile,"P%c\n%u %u\n1.0\n"` but in the following lines it **does** actually invert the endianness. I think the file will work if you just change `1.0` to `-1.0`.

Comment: Thank you Mark. It is exactly what I done with the code below, the following two posts solve this issue in two ways (with std and without).

Comment: But this issue (to not change scale value) is definitely a bug, which I reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not a proper answer but might work as a workaround for the time being.

I didn't find out how to properly invert the endianness using `CImg`s functions, so I modified the resulting file instead. It's a hack. The result opens fine in GIMP an looks very close to the original image, but I can't say if it works with the library you are using. It may be worth a try.

Comments in the code:

```
#include "CImg/CImg.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <filesystem> // >= C++17 must be selected as Language Standard
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace cimg_library;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

// a class to remove temporary files
class remove_after_use {
public:
    remove_after_use(const std::string& filename) : name(filename) {}
    remove_after_use(const remove_after_use&) = delete;
    remove_after_use& operator=(const remove_after_use&) = delete;

    const char* c_str() const { return name.c_str(); }
    operator std::string const& () const { return name; }

    ~remove_after_use() {
        try {
            fs::remove(name);
        }
        catch (const std::exception & ex) {
            std::cerr << "remove_after_use: " << ex.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
private:
    std::string name;
};

// The function to hack the file saved by CImg
template<typename T>
bool save_pfm_endianness_inverted(const T& img, const std::string& filename) {
    remove_after_use tempfile("tmp.pfm");

    // get CImg's endianness inverted image and save it to a temporary file
    img.get_invert_endianness().save_pfm(tempfile.c_str());

    // open the final file
    std::ofstream os(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // read "tmp.pfm" and modify
    // The Scale Factor / Endianness line
    if (std::ifstream is; os && (is = std::ifstream(tempfile, std::ios::binary))) {
        std::string lines[3];
        // Read the 3 PFM header lines as they happen to be formatted by
        // CImg. Will maybe not work with another library.
        size_t co = 0;
        for (; co < std::size(lines) && std::getline(is, lines[co]); ++co);

        if (co == std::size(lines)) { // success
            // write the first two lines back unharmed:
            os << lines[0] << '\n' << lines[1] << '\n';

            if (lines[2].empty()) {
                std::cerr << "something is wrong with the pfm header\n";
                return false;
            }

            // add a '-' if it's missing, remove it if it's there: 
            if (lines[2][0] == '-') {       // remove the - to invert
                os << lines[2].substr(1);
            }
            else {                          // add a - to invert
                os << '-' << lines[2] << '\n';
            }

            // copy all the rest as-is:
            std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is),
                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
                std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os));
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "failed reading pfm header\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "opening files failed\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    CImg<float> img("memorial.bmp");
    img.normalize(0.f, 1.f);
    std::cout << "saved ok: " << std::boolalpha
              << save_pfm_endianness_inverted(img, "memorial.pfm") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Seem to be ok now, in did is a workaround. Ted, can you explain to me this code ?                                                                                                                            // copy all the rest as-is:
            std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is),
                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
                std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os));

Comment: @flaviu2 Nice that the workaround seems to work. Perhaps a bugreport would be in order. `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is)` creates an input iterator using the `istream` object (`is`). `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}` creates an _end-of-stream iterator_ and `std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os)` creates an output iterator using `os` - then `std::copy` is used to copy from the input iterator to the output iterator - so it copies the rest of the file from the current `is` position to the current `os` position.

Comment: Ted, wanting to reproduce your idea, I encounter an issue, can you take a look ? I hope I would not push my luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to solve the same issue in classic C++ style (as language sake), I wrote:

```
BOOL CMyDoc::SavePfmEndiannessInverted(CImg<float>& img, const CString sFileName)
{
CString sDrive, sDir;
_splitpath(sFileName, sDrive.GetBuffer(), sDir.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL);

CString sTemp;
sTemp.Format(_T("%s%sTemp.tmp"), sDrive, sDir);

sDrive.ReleaseBuffer();
sDir.ReleaseBuffer();

CRemoveAfterUse TempFile(sTemp);
img.get_invert_endianness().save_pfm(TempFile.c_str());

CFile fileTemp;
if (! fileTemp.Open(sTemp, CFile::typeBinary))
    return FALSE;

char c;
UINT nRead = 0;
int nCount = 0;
ULONGLONG nPosition = 0;
CString sScale;
CByteArray arrHeader, arrData;
do
{
    nRead = fileTemp.Read((char*)&c, sizeof(char));
    switch (nCount)
    {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        arrHeader.Add(static_cast<BYTE>(c));
        break;
    case 2:             // retrieve the '1.0' string
        sScale += c;
        break;
    }
    if ('\n' == c)      // is new line
    {
        nCount++;
    }
    if (nCount >= 3)    // read the header, so go out
    {
        nPosition = fileTemp.GetPosition();
        break;
    }
}while (nRead > 0);

if (nPosition > 1)
{
    arrData.SetSize(fileTemp.GetLength() - nPosition);
    fileTemp.Read(arrData.GetData(), (UINT)arrData.GetSize());
}

fileTemp.Close();

CFile file;
if (! file.Open(sFileName, CFile::typeBinary | CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite))
    return FALSE;

CByteArray arrTemp;
ConvertCStringToByteArray(sScale, arrTemp);
arrHeader.Append(arrTemp);
arrHeader.Append(arrData);
file.Write(arrHeader.GetData(), (UINT)arrHeader.GetSize());
file.Close();

return TRUE;
}
```

But seem to not do the job, because the image result is darker

[image]

What I have done wrong here ? The code seem to me very clear, still, is not work as expected ...

Of course, this approach is more inefficient, I know, but as I said before, just for language sake.

I think it is nothing wrong with my code :)

Here is the trial:

```
CImg<float> image;
image.load_bmp(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.bmp"));
image.normalize(0.0f, 1.0f);
image.save_pfm(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.pfm"));
image.get_invert_endianness().save(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial_inverted.pfm"));
```

and the memorial.pfm looks like this:

[image: memorial.pfm]

and memorial_inverted.pfm looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The things I used were all standard C++ functions/classes. This new question with "_classic C++ style_" makes use of the MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) that I'm not familiar with - mainly because I try to use the standard C++ library as much as I can for portability - and for this task, I see no reason to step away from the standard library and loose portability at the same time. You won't find much use of MFC outside the Microsoft world so my advice is to familiarize yourself with the standard library instead. It'll pay off in the end :-)

Comment: I don't think I can avoid MFC though, it is a MFC project :)

Comment: :-) You don't have to avoid it, but you don't need to use it for things that are more easily solved using the standard either. Regarding the picture. It kind of looks like the picture I got when using `CImg::invert_endianness`. The actual data in the file was endianness-inverted, but the `Scale Factor / Endianness` line still said `1.0`. Have you looked in the pfm file to confirm that you successfully inverted the value on the `Scale Factor / Endianness` line?

Comment: Yes, the scale factor has been correctly written. The result image is a little bit whiter, but the same conversion made it with online converter output the same image.

Comment: Ok, so you get the same result as with my code now? If it's brighter, I expect that to be the result of normalizing. What happens if you: `1` read a BMP, `2` normalize, `3` save it as a new BMP. - Does this new BMP also show signs of being brighter?

Comment: Yes, with my code (from previous post) I get the same result with your code.

Comment: So, any code I use, the results are perfectly the same. Hre is my trials: 1. LoadBMP, normalize, save_pfm -> result is brighter.

Comment: The weird thing is that if I repeat the operation in the other direction: 1. LoadPFM, Normalize, Save_bmp, the outcome is the same as original ...

Comment: But, if I convert bmp with an online converter to pfm, the outcome is the same brighter ... only if I export bmp to pfm with GIMP, the pfm looks the same as original bmp.

Comment: I don't know if the source code of GIMP is available to check how they do this converion, from bmp to pfm ...

Comment: I don't think normalizing a picture twice will have any effect, so if you go from pfm->bmp, make sure that the pfm is not normalized first.

Would you mind testing what I suggested you should test too?

Comment: I must normalize the image even when I convert from pfm to bitmap, or else the image is black. *image.load_pfm(_T("D:\\Tempx\\memorial.pfm"));*... but I will try your idea.

Comment: image.load_pfm(_T("D:\\Tempx\\memorial.pfm"));
 image.normalize(0, 255);
 image.save_bmp(_T("D:\\Tempx\\memorial2.bmp"));
without *normalize* call, the resultimage are completely black

Comment: Ok, but what I suggested did not involve a pfm image. `1` load a BMP `2` normalize `3` save it as a new BMP. Compare the two BMP images.

Comment: I have tried this:
 CImg<float> image;
 image.load_bmp(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.bmp"));
 image.normalize(0, 255);
 image.save_bmp(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial2.bmp"));
and the memorial2.bmp is exactly the same.

Comment: if I try
 CImg<float> image;
 image.load_bmp(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial.bmp"));
 image.normalize(0, 1);
 image.save_bmp(_T("D:\\Temp\\memorial2.bmp"));
the memorial2.bmp is black

Comment: I wonder if `0,1` is really correct for a BMP. What about `0,255`?

Comment: 0 - 1 is needed for bmp->pfm, and 0-255 is needed for pfm->bmp conversion. without these normalize is not working … of course, if I convert bmp->bmp, there is no need any normalize, or, normalize 0-255.

Comment: No need perhaps. I was more interested in if it had any undesired effect. `0,255` should leave it "unharmed" I guess.

Comment: Have you also tried something like this? `CImg<unsigned char> img_bmp("memorial.bmp"); auto img_pfm = img_bmp.get_normalize(0.f, 1.f); img_pfm.save_pfm("memorial.pfm");` (I'm at work and can't try it out myself)

Comment: Hi Ted. I have tried your code and the result was the same image pfm file like my previous post, I mean a little bit whiter than original bitmap.

Comment: Ok, then it's perhaps something that is hard to avoid using `CImg`.